# When a view is dismissed, the presenting view throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, ipad, view, exc-bad-access, layer

I'm converting my iPhone app to an iPad version, creating new XIBs for the iPad and rigging them to the existing objective C classes using the ~ipad XIB name.

In the iPhone version, I use the navigation controller to step backwards to the app.  This should work just fine in the iPad too, but while the navigation controller does appear, it doesnt respond. In fact its invisible to any interaction, if theres a map behind the navigation controller and you double click back, you just zoom on the map where you clicked.

So I'm including a button in the iPad view which should do the same thing.  On press I call a

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

When I call this I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I've gone in to the spooky zombie mode which gives me this

```
*** -[UIWindowLayer superlayer]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x83bb9f0
```

Ive determined that `0x83bb9f0` is the presenting layers `self.view.layer`

I'm using ARC to handle my allocations and deallocs.

**THE QUESTION IS**: How can I prevent `self.view.layer` from deallocing? or how can I allocate it again at the proper time so that I dont get this error?

I can provide more code if needed.  Thanks so much!!

Edit: Heres where the main page (landing page) is created, and the nav controller

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    landingPage *LandingPage = [[landingPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"landingPage" bundle:nil];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:LandingPage];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:LandingPage animated:YES];

   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Then here is where the inner view is called:

```
mapView *MapView = nil;
        MapView =[[mapView alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:MapView animated:YES];
```

Comment: `mapView *MapView = nil;` Geez! You got that the wrong way around. Only classes (e.g. NSString, UIWindow) should start with capital letters. And why is a subclass of UIView_Controller_ called Map_View_? Confusing as hell.

Comment: check if your MapViewController class is the delegate of any other class. Most likely something calls a delegate method when the mapViewController has been popped and deallocated. Maybe a MKMapViewDelegate?

Comment: Yea I know, Its just hard to break the habit.  I promise to try harder!
Buuut I solved it, see below (in like 5 min)

Comment: Well I cant answer my own question yet so: 

OK I got it! The XIBs I was creating for the iPad version were windows instead of views.  
I recreated all of these as views and rigged it up and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I got it!

The XIBs I was creating for the iPad version were windows instead of views. I recreated all of these as views and rigged it up and it worked just fine!